Function declaration in the eval does not overwrite the previous one
Let's say we have code like below. The function a is declared twice. and we know  the output in the console should be

this is a2

because the second declaration of function a overwrite the previous function a.
function a ()
{
   console.log("this is a1");
}
function a ()
{
   console.log("this is a2");
}
a();

But the things are different when using eval.
Let's say we change the code like below.
eval("function a (){console.log (\"this is a1\")}");

function a ()
{
   console.log("this is a2");
}
a();

the output shows

this is a1

My question is why the function a is not overwritten in this scenario?

When you use eval inside a function (or globally), it defines variables and functions in the local scope of the eval call. If you define a in eval, this a is still accessible globally because it is a global function. But this doesn't re-declare the function at the same priority as actual function declarations made outside eval.

@AntonijaŠimić That's not exactly true; strict mode also plays a part here. See my answer (and the MDN page about eval).

For non-strict mode, this is about hoisting; your normal function a() { ... } function declaration gets (invisibly) hoisted to the top of the block, so it functionally happens before the eval.
$ cat aa.js
console.log(a.toString());  // If it wasn't for hoisting, this would be an error!
eval("function a (){console.log (\"this is a1\")}");
function a (){console.log("this is a2");}
a();

$ node aa.js
function a (){console.log("this is a2");}
this is a1

If you change it to an assignment of a function expression, this doesn't happen, since assignment statements aren't hoisted.
$ cat aa.js
eval("function a (){console.log (\"this is a1\")}");
var a = function a (){console.log("this is a2");}
a();

$ node aa.js
this is a2


eval's behavior in general also depends on the strictness mode of the surrounding context (which itself can be modulated depending on how you call eval).
In strict mode, the function does not leak out of the eval at all:
$ cat aa.js
"use strict";
eval("function a (){console.log (\"this is a1\")}");
function a (){console.log("this is a2");}
a();

$ node aa.js
this is a2


ah.. It is also about hoisting . I forgot this. Many thanks.

Because functions are hoisted, a() is available even if you define it after using eval():
eval("function a (){console.log (\"this is a1\")}"); // a() is hoisted, this will change a()

function a () // this is available right away (move to the top)
{
   console.log("this is a2");
}
a();


Can you explain a bit more? How hoisting affects this?

@AntonijaŠimić The hoisting would make all the declaration in the above of script. but the eval is not declaration. So when executing eval the statement overwrite the function declaration which is hoisting in my scenario.
